# is there an analogue of 'counstuctor' mobx in redux-toolkit?

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, mobx

We have a store with an application theme
We want to rewrite it in redux-toolkit
Is there something similar to "constructor" in redux-toolkit so that multiple functions can be called sequentially when creating a store?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tebf.png)

I looked through many sites but could not find a solution to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Just write it after `configureStore`:

```js
const store = configureStore(...)
store.dispatch(..)
store.dispatch(..)
store.dispatch(..)
```

and if you need to create stores multiple times (probably only ever in SSR scenarios, usually you should have one store per running application, so in the browser: one), wrap all of that in a function.